# "took the pill for in avarice"

Tags: grammar

I was reading Wikipedia's page about Chinese folklore and encountered this sentence where I don't quite understand the meaning of "take the pill for in avarice":

> "In some versions of this tale, Chang'e took the pill for in avarice
> and she transformed into a three-legged Ch'an Chu and eventually flew
> to the moon."

As I get it, it's some kind of inversion takes place here because "took in the pill for avarice" but I'm not sure

Comment: Please provide a link in future. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_folklore The example is obviously a mistake. It is hard to say what it actually means. You could omit it -> *Chang'e took the pill ____ and she transformed into a three-legged Ch'an Chu ...* or read it as *Greedily, Chang'e took the pill and she transformed into a three-legged Ch'an Chu ...*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misprint/typo/poor translation.

Answer (score 2):

"In avarice" is awkward here and wouldn't be used this way by a native speaker. The Wikipedia text was clearly not written by a native speaker.

In the much more clearly written article on [Chang'e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e) herself we see:

> Ten suns had risen together into the skies and scorched the Earth, thus causing hardship for the people.[ Houyi the archer shot down nine of them, leaving just one Sun, and was given either two or one with enough for two elixirs of immortality as a reward. He did not consume it straight away, but let Chang'e keep it with her, as he did not want to gain immortality without his beloved wife.

> In older versions of the story, **Chang'e stole the elixir from Houyi, drank it, and flew to the Moon so that her husband could not go after her**.

This version makes it clear she took the elixir selfishly. So the first writer probably intended "in avarice" to be an adverbial meaning, i.e. ***avariciously, greedily***. The word "for" is spurious.

Answer (score 1):

The surrounding sentences show that the passage this text is from is not grammatical English. It may be a machine translation from another language.

- For expressing gratitude god rewarded him with pill which is an immortal elixir. In some versions of this tale, Chang'e **took the pill for in avarice** and she transformed into a three-legged Ch'an Chu and eventually flew to the moon. Hou Yi loved his wife so much that God allowed him to reunite annually with Chang'e at moment of the full moon on the 15th of August in Chinese lunar calendar, which is the celebration of Mid-Autumn Festival. From then on, the moon and Chang'e relate to the toad comprise the significance eternal and reunion.*